# python detect asymptote of a curve

Tags: python, feature-construction

I have a curve like this :

[image]

typical second order equation. I would like to auto detect the asymptote value (the red line). Do you know if it exist a python built in function to do that (like peakdetection function for peaks) ? Or have I to regress the curve first, then identifying value at infinity ?

Thanks